# Facebook SDK for android - getting access token by passing username and password

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

Is there a way to get access token by passing the username and password with a method (Not to use the authorize method of the SDK)??

I want to have something like this:

```
private String GetFacebookAccessToken(String username , String password ){
 ...
}
```

In my app I want to have 2 facebook accounts , I want each time to login with a different account , I have the username & password saved.

Please help...

Comment: If such a function would exist in the Facebook SDK, Facebook would basically require 3rd party app developers to ask users for their login credentials - that's very sensitive information. In such a scenario no one could stop the 3rd party app developer from impersonating that user, steal data or money from them. It's in the best interest of users and Facebook not to have such a login function.

Comment: The problem in my app is that I have Facebook installed on my device it does not give me the option to login with different user. When I use the authorize method it allready detects my facebook account from the device. How can I make the user to his credentials every time , because I want different account in each time.

Answer (score 0):

See how this is implemented in this sample: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/tree/master/samples/SwitchUserSample

That uses the LoginBehavior.SUPPRESS_SSO which is what you're seeing.